# Get systemjob id of current running system job (AsyncOperation Entity)

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2015

I'm writing a Dynamics CRM 2015 plugin, that is triggered by the sdk message step "assign of Task" and runs asynchronously.

In `Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)` method, I want to search for other currently running system jobs, using a `QueryExpression`:

```csh
QueryExpression systemjobq = new QueryExpression
{
    EntityName = "asyncoperation",
    ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("name", "createdon", "completedon", "regardingobjectid", "asyncoperationid", "startedon", "messagename", "statuscode"),
    Criteria = new FilterExpression
    {
        Conditions = {
                        new ConditionExpression 
                        {
                            AttributeName = "name",
                            Operator = ConditionOperator.Equal,
                            Values = { "My system jobs name" }
                        }
                     }
    }
};
```

Because I don't want to find "myself" - the currently running system job - I need to find out the `asyncoperationid` of the currently running system job that executes my plugin, so I can include it in my search query expression.

How can I find out the `asyncoperationid` of the currently running system job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you would like to find the record of the async job in which your async plugin is currently executing. Try the following extension method:

```csh
   public static EntityCollection GetCurrentAsyncJob(this IOrganizationService service, ColumnSet cols, Guid EntityId, Guid OwnerId) {

            QueryExpression systemjobq = new QueryExpression
            {
                EntityName = "asyncoperation",
                ColumnSet = cols,//new ColumnSet("name", "createdon", "completedon", "regardingobjectid", "asyncoperationid", "startedon", "messagename", "statuscode"),
                Criteria = new FilterExpression
                {
                    Conditions = 
                    {
                        new ConditionExpression 
                        {
                            AttributeName = "regardingobjectid",
                            Operator = ConditionOperator.Equal,
                            Values = {EntityId}
                        },
                        new ConditionExpression {
                        AttributeName = "statuscode",
                        Operator = ConditionOperator.In,
                        Values = {20}
                        },
                        new ConditionExpression 
                        {
                            AttributeName = "ownerid",
                            Operator = ConditionOperator.Equal,
                            Values = {OwnerId}
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            systemjobq.Orders.Add(new OrderExpression { AttributeName = "createdon", OrderType = OrderType.Descending });
            return service.RetrieveMultiple(systemjobq);
        }
```

You can check if you are getting an Id of the Async job as follows, where `service` is your IOrganization service in the plugin and `taskId` is the id of your task, against which the plugin is currently running, and the `OwnerId` is the current initiating owner of the plugin:

```csh
     EntityCollection ents = service.GetCurrentAsyncJob(new ColumnSet(new []{"name", "createdon", "completedon", "regardingobjectid", "asyncoperationid", "startedon", "messagename", "statuscode"}), TaskId, OwnerId);
            if (ents.Entities.Count > 0)
                throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(ents.Entities.FirstOrDefault().Id.ToString());
            else throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("M? Really, No?");
```

This is how you get the current user in the plugin, from your plugin context:

```csh
Guid userId = context.InitiatingUserId;
```

The method is not perfect, as it will return multiple jobs if they exist related to this entity, and the assign is fired for the same task concurrently. I am not sure and have not tested this, though I think it will only be a problem if your plugin is selected to run under the same user.

*Note that the extension method must be placed in a static class.*

*Note2: Status equal to 20 means the async job is still running and InProgress.*

Please try and see if it works out for you.

Comment: Hi Bojan,thx for your reply. in fact, it's not exactly what I was going to archive. My intention was to find all other currently running system jobs, that arent the current one, i'm currently running my code in. What I found out is that you can get the asyncobjectid of the current running "thread" from the context with `context.OperationId`.